# Cathing exception is getting error in flutter. The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Exception'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new on flutter. The Flutter version is 2.5.0

I have a class that name is SubmissionFailed.

```
class SubmissionFailed extends FormSubmissionStatus {
  final Exception exception;

  SubmissionFailed(this.exception);
}
```

When I try to call this class in a try/catch block it gives an error.

> Error is : The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'Exception'

Here is the try/catch block:

[image]

I do not understand what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the argument `exception` doesn't have a type in the catch block declaration, so Flutter keeps it safe by considering it to be of type Object. Why? Just like in Java, if no extended class is defined, all classes in Dart automatically extend the class Object. Basically, every single class in Dart inherits (directly or indirectly) from Object.

The `SubmissionFailed` constructor has one parameter of type `Exception`, which means you can't pass an `Object` or any other type, it has to be of `Exception` type.

To fix this, just cast it like this:

```
try {
  // code
} catch (exception) {
  yield state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionFailed(exception as Exception));
}
```

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Comment: It would be much better to fix the `catch` block to be `on Exception catch (exception)` and avoid the cast.  Otherwise if something else is thrown (such as an `Error`), it won't be overshadowed by a subsequent `CastError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your object `as Exception` for using it